how to conver new key into old in python3 ndb
Here my code
  new_key= ndb.Key(urlsafe = request.user_key)

this is written in python3 ndb
this will return us key and we change in urlsafe
key = new_key.urlsafe()
key.decode(encoding="utf-8")

but this is not return us new key which does not match with python2 key
now google app engine has change not sport python2 but they gave us this method
to_old_key

but this does not work
https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/key.html
https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/_modules/google/cloud/ndb/key.html#Key.to_old_key
how can we use this

Can you explain about your infrastructure? Also share minimal replicating steps or documents and logs? Also have a look at this Link1 and Link2.

Note - This isn't really about Python 2 vs Python 3. It looks like you want to convert an ndb to a db key

What you're asking for isn't possible/supported with cloud ndb. According to the documentation you linked to, the method


Raises:
NotImplementedError: Always.

So, that method will always raise error if you're using cloud ndb. The documentation points you to from_old_key for the reason for it not being supported.

The old_key was expected to be a google.appengine.ext.db.Key (which
was an alias for google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key).
However, the google.appengine.ext.db module was part of the legacy
Google App Engine runtime and is not generally available.


You should try the bundled APIs i.e. google.appengine.ext.ndb. I can still see the method in the code and it's set to return a valid value

